# Apache Storm - Could not find or load main class org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I'm really new to maven and storm so I'm trying to follow the instructions in https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter. My current path is /home/luc/theTest/storm/examples/storm-starter. Inside the target folder there is a storm-starter-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file. I'm getting stuck when running

> storm jar target/storm-starter-*.jar org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology -local

I get this error

> ionTopology -local
> Running: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1 -Dstorm.log.dir=/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/objenesis-2.1.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/kryo-3.0.3.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/storm-core-1.1.1.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/minlog-1.3.0.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/log4j-api-2.8.2.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/clojure-1.7.0.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/ring-cors-0.1.5.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/reflectasm-1.10.1.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/disruptor-3.3.2.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/lib/storm-rename-hack-1.1.1.jar:target/storm-starter-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/conf:/home/luc/stormTest/apache-storm-1.1.1/bin -Dstorm.jar=target/storm-starter-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dstorm.dependency.jars= -Dstorm.dependency.artifacts={} org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology -local
> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology

Am I doing something wrong? I'm also a bit confused on whether I have to run the nimbus and supervisor first. I tried with and without them and neither worked anyways. Been searching the web but nothing works. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Based on your logs, your storm-client is version 1.1.1 and your starter is `2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually caused by inconsistent versions of storm-client and storm-starter. Try following these steps to get the example working.

1. download the latest release from `http://storm.apache.org/downloads.html`

   - in this example, we will use version 1.1.1
2. extract this to a folder, lets call it `${STORM_HOME}`
3. cd into `${STORM_HOME}/examples/storm-starter`
4. execute `mvn package -DskipTests=true`

   - this should build the storm-starter jar in target folder 
     `${STORM_HOME}/examples/storm-starter/target/storm-starter-1.1.1.jar`
5. run the example from `${STORM_HOME}` directory: 
   `./bin/storm jar examples/storm-starter/target/storm-starter-1.1.1.jar org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology`

don't add the `-local` flag since it seems like the `ExclamationTopology` is only deployed in a `LocalCluster` if no args are passed. You can check the source code here: 
`${STORM_HOME}/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/starter/ExclamationTopology.java`

Comment: Ty! I spent 4 days trying to figure this out.   Yeah I downloaded storm first, set it up and then forgot about it.  I then cloned the github to do the tutorial.  I feel stupid lol. Tried to upvote but don't have enough reputation. Ty!

Comment: @luc no worries, appreciate it if you could accept my answer though. :)

Comment: Should build instructions be updated at https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/v2.1.0/examples/storm-starter ?
It seems to me like the steps outlined there will lead one to run the `storm jar` command using the source rather than a release build. And this always fails with `The storm client can only be run from within a release.`